# The argument type 'FlutterTagging can`t be assigned to the parameter type `Widget`

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I try to use external widget (https://github.com/sarbagyastha/flutter_tagging). I know, that its garantee worked at the android-version. But I add it at Web-version and get error "The argument type 'FlutterTagging cant be assigned to the parameter type Widget`". It is only the simple code (example "Hello, World", nothing more). Is it suppose to work at Web-version?

The main code inherited from Widget - class, its clear from source. And I dont knoww whats that error meaning.

```
    import 'package:flutter_web/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_tagging/flutter_tagging.dart';

    void main() => runApp(MyApp());

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      // This widget is the root of your application.
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),
          home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
      }
    }

    class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
      MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Hello, World!',
                ),
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child:

                        FlutterTagging(
                          textFieldDecoration: InputDecoration(
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                              hintText: "Tags",
                              labelText: "Enter tags"),
                          addButtonWidget: _buildAddButton(),
                          chipsColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
                          chipsFontColor: Colors.white,
                          deleteIcon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.white),
                          chipsPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                          chipsFontSize: 14.0,
                          chipsSpacing: 5.0,
                          chipsFontFamily: 'helvetica_neue_light',
                          suggestionsCallback: (pattern) async {
                            return await TagSearchService.getSuggestions(pattern);
                          },
                          onChanged: (result) {
                            setState(() {
                              text = result.toString();
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20.0,
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text(

                          'test',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
        );
      }

    }

    Widget _buildAddButton() {
      return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          color: Colors.pinkAccent,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.add,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 15.0,
            ),
            Text(
              "Add New Tag",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14.0),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Comment: Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.1 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision a1fb3fabec (4 days ago) • 2019-09-03 18:07:52 -0700
Engine • revision cc88fa45db
Tools • Dart 2.5.0

Flutter Doctor - ok.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in flutter web, all widgets need to be a subclass of `Widget` class from `package:flutter_web/material.dart`. Whereas the widget that you are using extends the `Widget` class from `package:flutter/material.dart`. As Flutter and Flutter web are separate projects right now, you'll have to change the source code to use `package:flutter_web/material.dart` instead of `package:flutter/material.dart`. Most of the time, just replacing the import statement does the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My error was gone. But then "webdev serve" and I have got "You have a dependency on `flutter` which is not supported for flutter_web tech preview. See https://flutter.dev/web for more details." Think, its need a waiting.

Comment: don't use any flutter packages. If you want to use any flutter package in your app, copy - paste its source code and `package:flutter/material.dart` to `package:flutter_web/material.dart`.